# neo4j: extraction of random graphs

Tags: graph, neo4j, extract, random-access

We have a big graph database made with `Neo4j` which has two type of relationships "E" and "I".
We would like to extract two graphs from it with a starting node called n0.
The first graph `Gxi`, based on the `"I"` relationship, must be obtained randomly.
The following request is wrong but this is the idea we want to implement. Here 10 neighbors are randomly chosen for each node of the last step

```
MATCH r1:(n0)-[:I]-(n1)
WITH random(n1) LIMIT 10
MATCH r2:(n1)-[:I]-(n2)
WITH random(n2) LIMIT 10*10
MATCH r3:(n2)-[:I]-(n3)
WITH random(n3) LIMIT 10*10*10
MATCH r4:(n4)-[:I]-(n4)
WITH random(n4) LIMIT 10*10*10*10
RETURN r1+r2+r3+r4
```

Then we would like to create the second graph `Gxe` based on the relationships `"E"` and the nodes of `Gxi`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) may be able to help here. There are collection functions that can be used to choose random items from a collection, and you can get slices of the collection rather than having to use LIMIT.

The trickier part will actually be collecting the subpaths along the way.

```
// assume already matched to start node n
MATCH r = (n)-[:I]-()
WITH apoc.coll.randomItems(collect(r), 10) as r1
UNWIND r1 as r
WITH r1, last(nodes(r)) as n

MATCH r = (n)-[:I]-()
WITH r1, apoc.coll.randomItems(collect(r), 10) as r2
UNWIND r2 as r
WITH r1, r2, last(nodes(r)) as n

MATCH r = (n)-[:I]-()
WITH r1, r2, apoc.coll.randomItems(collect(r), 10) as r3
UNWIND r3 as r
WITH r1, r2, r3, last(nodes(r)) as n

MATCH r = (n)-[:I]-()
WITH r1, r2, r3, apoc.coll.randomItems(collect(r), 10) as r4
RETURN r1 + r2 + r3 + r4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for this answer that works very well !